# Checking whether items haven't been submitted in the last 3 days gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running this query where I am checking whether an Item was submitted in the last 3 days. However the way I have the `WHERE` clause it's showing all items when the `UD.Submitted` `>` greater than the calculated date, but if I switch it around I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'JYA3AWE091A087443' to data type int.

Reading the error I get that its a type conversion error, I just don't know how to fix this. `UD.Submitted` is of type `smalldatetime` I'm guessing that the `DATEADD()` function is the same type or of some kind of date like value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT
    U.Id
    , U.Serial_N
    , UD.Submitted      
FROM UNIT U
LEFT JOIN UNIT_DATES UD ON U.Id = UD.Id
WHERE UD.Submitted < DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE()))
    AND U.Serial_N = 1234567890
```

Comment: The date logic is not causing this problem.

Comment: So If I take the `AND U.Serical_N = 1234567890` out it runs. does that mean its trying to compare a `null` value then?

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE())` does nothing useful. Simplify your life. And your problem is that U.Serial_N is a varchar column which you compare to an integer literal. Due to datatype precedence and implicit conversion, your column (containing many values that are not numbers) is converted to integer for the comparison. Hence, the error.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: why the down vote with no explanation?

Comment: Firstly there is no requirement for an explanation, secondly if you hover your mouse over the down-vote arrow you can see the reasons, my guess here is "your question is unclear", which can be deduced from the comments above. And FYI it wasn't me.

Comment: Your error appears to be that you aren't quoting your string e.g. `U.Serial_N = 1234567890` should be `U.Serial_N = '1234567890'` - leaving out the quotes means its treated as a number, but from the error that column is not a number. (As Smor has already said earlier).

Comment: Otherwise your 3 day logic is correct. If its not working as expected please post some sample data and expected results (as formatted text not images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as stated above by @Dale K I wasn't quoting my `U.Serial_N`, so getting some sample data I found out that it's not just number but also other characters. It just so happen that the results I was getting where all numeric. Adding ' ' around fixed it.

**example data from a later date**

```
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
|  ID   |   Serial_Number   |   Date Submitted    |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 95131 | 5LMFU28508LJ12116 | 2020-02-13 14:36:00 |
| 95132 | 3GYFK66N66G128591 | 2020-02-13 14:38:00 |
| 95133 | 1234567890        | 2020-02-13 14:39:00 |
+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: To be fair @SMor said it first.

Comment: If you had included DDL it would have been almost obvious. The technical answer is that you ran afoul of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). And it leaves unexplained the mystery of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-type) vs. `CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE())`.